# Access $(this) DOM element from within jQuery Autocomplete Widget Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, coffeescript

In the code below (Coffeescript), in the AJAX call for the jQuery autocomplete data source, On line 5 of the code, I am passing 2 params - term: and ll:
For ll: I'm trying to get $(this) to be the DOM element that .autocomplete was applied to.  In this case its $('[type="text"][name*="[location]"]')
I need to reference that DOM element specifically with ($this) on line 5.  However, I believe 'this' at that scope refers to something else that isn't a DOM element.  Can someone please help explain what I need to do?

```
$('[type="text"][name*="[location]"]').autocomplete(
    source: (request, response) ->
      $.ajax 
        url: $('[type="text"][name*="[location]"]').data('autocomplete-source')
        data: {term: request.term, ll: $(this).siblings('[name*="[geocode_location]"]')}
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        success: (data) ->
          response $.map(data, (item) ->
            value: item.value
            label: item.label
            address: item.address
          )

    focus: (event, ui) ->
      event.preventDefault()
      $(this).val ui.item.label
    select: (event, ui) ->
      event.preventDefault()
      $(this).val ui.item.label
      $(this).siblings('[name*="[foursquare_id]"]').val ui.item.value
  ).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = (ul, item) ->
    $("<li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.address + "</a>").appendTo ul
```

Comment: Your autocomplete argument object is missing a starting curly brace.

Comment: I don't know coffeescript, but a quick glance at the documentation suggests that it omits many of the usual JS curly braces.

Comment: @Barmar is correct, coffeescript doesn't require that curly brace. Everything works except for my call to $(this) in line 5 of the code. I know that everything works because I substituted it with just a string and know that it works.  My question is around the scope of ($this) because at line 5, ($this) doesn't refer to the original DOM element that autocomplete function was applied on. I need it to though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell you anything about Coffeescript, but **`this.element`** should return the element(it's an jQuery-object)

So it should be:

```
ll:this.element.siblings('[name*="[geocode_location]"]')
```

But this will not work, because siblings returns an jQuery-object and could not be passed as a request-parameter.

Comment: Yes!!! this.element worked! Thank you so much. I spent this whole morning trying to figure this out.  It's such a simple answer! I'll post my complete answer in another answer for anyone else that it might help.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the curly bracket in the autocomplete function and you're selector isn't working in my test case..

try this jQuery selector:

```
$('input[type="text"][name*="location"]').autocomplete({ ....
```

Comment: Everything works except for my call to $(this) in line 5 of the code. I know that everything works because I substituted it with just a string and know that it works.  My question is around the scope of ($this) because at line 5, ($this) doesn't refer to the original DOM element that autocomplete function was applied on. I need it to though.

Answer (score 0):

like @Dr.Molle suggested, this.element helps to get the DOM element that I wanted. Updated code block below. See the 5th line for how I applied it.

```
$('[type="text"][name*="[location]"]').autocomplete(
    source: (request, response) ->
      $.ajax 
        url: $('[type="text"][name*="[location]"]').data('autocomplete-source')
        data: {term: request.term, ll: this.element.siblings('[name*="[geocode_location]"]').val()}
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        success: (data) ->
          response $.map(data, (item) ->
            value: item.value
            label: item.label
            address: item.address
          )

    focus: (event, ui) ->
      event.preventDefault()
      $(this).val ui.item.label
    select: (event, ui) ->
      event.preventDefault()
      $(this).val ui.item.label
      $(this).siblings('[name*="[foursquare_id]"]').val ui.item.value
  ).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = (ul, item) ->
    $("<li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.address + "</a>").appendTo ul
```