# Access $(this) in jQuery autocomplete function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery's [autocomplete widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and am trying to use it on multiple elements on the same page and pull in their individual attributes dynamically, rather than having to make a separate unique call for each search box. Each search box has a class of `autocomplete-search` and contains some `data` attributes specific for its use case.

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="brand" id="brand" class="autocomplete-search" data-search-url="/api/v1/search">
<input type="text" name="product" id="product" class="autocomplete-search" data-search-url="/api/v1/search">

$('.autocomplete-search').autocomplete({
  source: $(this).data("search-url"),
});
```

However this breaks with `TypeError: this.source is not a function. (In 'this.source( { term: value }, this._response() )', 'this.source' is null)`. I realize this question is similar to [Access $(this) DOM element from within jQuery Autocomplete Widget Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185331/access-this-dom-element-from-within-jquery-autocomplete-widget-ajax-call) but the accepted answer there is not working here. `this.element` also responds with the same error.

I cannot seem to find an answer to this after reading through the autocomplete docs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `this` supposed to represent in your case?

Comment: @Zenoo the element that `autocomplete` was called on; so a specific search box. I just updated the question to include the markup of the 2 example inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the `autocomplete` widget on multiple elements.

As far as I know, you can't tell the widget to select a dynamic source for every element.

Another way would be to loop through your elements and call the `autocomplete` inside that loop using jQuery [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function :

```
$('.autocomplete-search').each(function(){
  $(this).autocomplete({
    source: $(this).data("search-url")
  });
});
```

Comment: That makes sense. Let me try that.

Comment: Awesome man. That seems to have done the trick! Appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.